# Assign Specific Dataype in case of var

Tags: c#, types, var, provider

How To assign Specific Data type instead of var in Following case

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Comment: you could write CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; what is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio you can see the type when hover on the var keyword :

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo nonInvariantCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = nonInvariantCulture;
```